Connecting Raspberry to Windows with Python
I want to communicate between Raspberry and Windows using Python and transfer files. I want to do this without needing an internet connection or a cable. I tried connecting with a socket connection, but since the Raspberry IP address has changed, there is no guarantee of a subsequent connection. How can I make this connection without having to intervene in the Raspberry again?
I tried using my Raspberry Pi as a hotspot.
